# Logstash : use environment variable

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have tried to follow the documentation 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/environment-variables.html
but it does not seem to work.

I have a bunch of log files to process.
Say I have an input file  /share/log-2017.09.07.json that I am trying to process with logstash.

An excerpt of my logstash config file is as follows :

```
input {   file {
     'exclude' => ['*.gz']
     'path' => ["/share/log-${INPUT_DATE}.json"]
     'type' => 'json'
     start_position => "beginning"
     codec  => json
     sincedb_path => "/dev/null"   
  } 
}
```

I launch logstash as follows :

```
export INPUT_DATE="2017.09.07"
logstash -f myconfigfile.conf
```

The logstash does not seem to find the file /share/log-2017.09.03.json.
When I replace

```
     'path' => ["/share/log-${INPUT_DATE}.json"]
```

by

```
     'path' => ["/share/log-2017.09.07.json"]
```

it works.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/environment-variables.html this document ${var} works only below situations.

- port => "${TCP_PORT}"  ,   export TCP_PORT=12345
- add_tag => [ "tag1", "${ENV_TAG}" ] ,  export ENV_TAG="tag2"
- add_field => {"my_path" => "${HOME}/file.log"  , export HOME="/path"

but in your code you used ${var} in below place.
'path' => ["/share/log-${INPUT_DATE}.json"] in here /log- must also be in variable. 
**export INPUT_DATE="log-2017.09.07.json"**
according to documentation examples , they used this function for few events, not for all situations.

Answer (score 0):

1. [If your logstash is in a docker container] Set your variable to default (only its name) in your docker-compose.yml:

   environment:
         - INPUT_DATE
2. You need to run `export INPUT_DATE="2017.09.07"` and start your docker in the same command line session.

Answer (score 0):

Replacement variable `INPUT_DATE` is not defined in

- a Logstash secret store
- or as an Environment entry
- and there is no default value given.",

This probably means that Logstash .conf file has no access an environment variable set from an external shell script.